# Hindi font is not showing in 32 bit machine. (windows 7) what could be the possible reason?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, unicode, hindi

Application made in java and we r using apache-tomcat-7.0.81-windows-x86 ,  postgresql-9.5.3-1-windows, jre 7 all for 32 bit machine. 
the application is running successfully on the machine but hindi font is coming as question mark(?).
unicode tag used in jsp,
also the data in database in hindi.
we also added utf encoding in server.xml in tomcat..
but still it is showing question mark ?.

And the same configuration working on 64 bit windows.

Comment: Is this tomcat or the browser running in 32 bit? What happens when you access a 32bit tomcat with a 64bit browser?

Comment: Yes it is running on 32 bit.

Comment: What is "it"? Browser or Tomcat? Both?

Comment: Browser and Tomcat both.. The problem is hindi font is appearing as question mark(label)..